# How to hide a div, when we are on a specific route?

Tags: angularjs, html

Here is my HTML file :

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <!-- Title -->
          <span class="mdl-layout__title">App</span>
          <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
          <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only mdl-typography--body-1-force-preferred-font">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" ui-sref="map" ui-sref-active="active">Carte</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" ui-sref="search" ui-sref-active="active">Recherche</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" ui-sref="admin" ui-sref-active="active">Admin</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
      <!-- Navigation pannel, we show it only on smaller screen -->
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer mdl-layout--small-screen-only">
        <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-typography--body-1-force-preferred-font">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" ui-sref="map" ui-sref-active="active">Carte</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" ui-sref="search" ui-sref-active="active">Recherche</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" ui-sref="admin" ui-sref-active="active">Admin</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
<main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div ng-controller="GlobalController as globalCtrl">
        <div class="mdl-grid" >
        </div>
</main>
```

My routing.js file, in order to have the rights views in the code (I dont post this part on the HTML file) :

```
(function() {

angular.module('app.routing', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider
    .when('', '/map')
    .when('/', '/map');
  $stateProvider
    .state('map', {
      url: '/map',
      templateUrl: 'views/map.html',
      controller: 'MapController as mapCtrl'
    })
    .state('search', {
      url: '/search',
      templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
      controller: 'SearchController as searchCtrl'
    })
    .state('admin', {
      url: '/admin',
      templateUrl: 'views/admin.html',
      controller: 'ValueController as valueCtrl'
    });
});

})();
```

I just want to hide the div mdl-grid in the main part, if I am on the admin bar and not the map and search ones. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you are missing one thing: ui-view

Change the line

```
<div class="mdl-grid" ></div>
```

for

```
<div class="mdl-grid" ui-view></div>
```

And only the specific view will be displayed inside this div

More documentation can be found [here](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/views)

Comment: I can add two views in parameters, for ui view ?

I have already an other ui-view in the HTML code.

Comment: Yes, I think. Look at [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Comment: I think what @SimonGirard is trying to do is not changing views here (I suppose that works fine). He just want to simply hide a div.

Comment: If . you want to hide a div depending on your state, you can use the $state object

$state.current.name will give you the same of the current state. You can have a variable like this in your controller.

    let isStateAdmin = ( $state.current.name === admin)

And use ng-if in your view to display your div or not based on this

Comment: @lealceldeiro : that's it. I have trying to put all the grid, in the previous views, it works, except some details...

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class and add a class that hide or show the view from your controller.

HTML

```
<div ng-class="mdlGridClass">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hide{ display: none;}

.show{ display: block;}
```

Controller

```
$scope.mdlGridClass = "mdl-grid hide"; // FOR HIDING DIV IN admin route

$scope.mdlGridClass = "mdl-grid show"; // FOR SHOWING DIV IN OTHERS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$state.current.name` to get the name of the current state. And an `ngIf` to show or not show depending of the current state. Look a [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3B6OPX0R24jnMHzXYbUt?p=preview) if it's what you are looking for

Comment: I put it, in a controller, but, when I make a reference to "$state.current" in the HTML page, I have :
{"name":"","url":"^","views":null,"abstract":true}

Comment: @SimonGirard Probably because you are in the root state `'/'`. If not, I need more code to help you

Comment: @SimonGirard When you say "a reference to '$state.current' in the HTML page", if you mean a reference to `statenow` in your service `ApplicationState`. It's normal that the value is `{"name":"","url":"^","views":null,"abstract":true}` because when this service is initialized your are in the default state which is `{"name":"","url":"^","views":null,"abstract":true}`. And the line `appliState.statenow=JSON.stringify($state.current);` is called only 1 time and even if the state change the value of `statenow` will not change.

Comment: So you need, in the controller of the HTML page where you want to show the value of the current state, to have a reference to `$state` and to store it in a scope variable to have access to it in your view (like this `$scope.myState` and in your view you directly make reference to this variable (if you want to show current state value, like this : `{{myState.current}}`). Maybe I'm not really clear, but take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3B6OPX0R24jnMHzXYbUt?p=preview) how I did it.